# Import CSV into MySQL - Offset by 1 Column

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import

I am importing my data from a `csv` file like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "c:\myfile.csv" INTO TABLE historic FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This ALMOST works perfect.  My table has one different row, the first: An auto incremented `id` column.  Otherwise the `csv` file and the `MySQL` table match perfectly.  When I run the command above, it puts the first column from the `csv` into the `id` field.  It want it to actually go into the second.

Is there a way I can modify the above statement to either specify the columns or just offset it by 1? (skipping the first column on import).

Comment: Have you tried to load it first into a temporary table, and use a select into your final table? So you are able to specify the columns that you want on it.

Comment: @vinibarr No I haven't.  I wanted to first see if this was possible in one command.

Comment: I know that you are able to ignore columns from the source file, but ignore columns on your destiny table I think is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your data specifing the order columns that you're going to use into your table:
    LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE historic
    (name_field1, name_field2, name_field3...);

Or if you prefer you can load it first to a temporary table and use a select into statement to laod it into your final table (it's slower).

Answer (score 2):

You can optionally name the columns to be populated by LOAD DATA, and simply omit your `id` column:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "c:\myfile.csv" INTO TABLE historic 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(column2, colum3, column4, column5, ...)
```